# How to fill a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

Starting from

```
char tval[20] = "temp:26.62";
```

how can I add a space character until `tval` is filled? I need that in the end to obtain this:

```
char tval[20] = "temp:26.62          ";
```

Comment: Anything to stop you from iterating through the entire array and setting every \0 to a space?  Fair warning, you need a \0 terminator at the end of every c string

Comment: space or null? If you need null, you're already there.

Comment: Space. I'm a newbie in C and so far I failed in filling the array. I just need to send a 20 byte data through Bluetooth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this, probably

```
size_t prevlen = strlen(tval);
memset(tval + prevlen, ' ', 19 - prevlen);
*(tval + 19) = '\0';
```

Comment: The last line is redundant. The rest of the entire array is initialized to '\0'. Writing an assert would be much better, because currently the code is concealing a potential bug, if the programmer uses an incorrect constant values in memset(). It is also better to use sizeof to determine the size of the array, rather than a constant value.

Comment: Please guys - add some comments. I am a new C user and I can read the code, b ut I do not fully understand it yet; in particular memset() confuses me. The vote here is accepted as answer, but I think the answer lacks explanations, whereas the answer below DOES have some explanations.

Comment: Like @shevy suggests, would someone PLEASE comment this? I'm a C-language noob and can read it but have no idea why the `memset` call is constructed like it is. I'd love to upvote the answer, but I can't justify it yet.

Comment: @ifconfig ```memset(tval + prevlen, ' ', 19 - prevlen);```
```void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);```
memset fills the bytes after ```temp:26.62``` with space and we need to specify how many bytes for memset to fill. That is calculated by ```19-prevlen``` . 19 instead of 20 means we have left a byte for ```\0```

Comment: @Karthick that would look much better as an edit to the answer.  Code never looks quite right in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

If `tval[20]` is a fixed size and that `20` is always gonna be the size, you can iterate through the array and do this:

```
char tval[20] = "temp:26.62";
```

What happens now is that your char `tval[20]` looks like this:

```
{'t','e','m','p',':','2','6','.','6','2','\0'}
```

The rest will be filled with `\0`

You can now iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
if (tval[i] == '\0')
   {
    tval[i] = ' ';
   }
}
```

It is important that you terminate the string with a nullbyte.
If you choose not to, you can not use any string functions on the char array because you will be invoking undefined behavior if you do so.

Comment: It didn't worked initially, probably because of `tval[i] == ' ';` (see double equal)

Comment: The additional `tval[19] = '\0';` terminator is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the tables are initialized by the indication of the list of array elements in braces:

​​`char tval [] = {'H', 'e', ​​'l', 'l', 'o', '\ 0'};`

> For the special case character arrays, we can use a more comfortable
>   boot simply stating a constant string:

```
char tval [] = "Hello";
```

During initialization by [], the computer automatically reserves the number of bytes required for the chain, ie .: the number of character + 1 (here: 6 bytes). We can also explicitly specify the number of bytes to be reserved, if it is greater or equal to the length of the initialization string.

Comment: Right, but how it is applicable in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char tval[20] = "temp:26.62";

    size_t length = strlen(tval);

    printf("Length of TVAL Before = %zu\n", length);

    while(length < 19){
        tval[length] = ' ';
        length++;
    }

    tval[19] = '\0';

    printf("Length of TVAL After =  %zu\n",length);
    printf("TVAL = %s\n",tval);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Length of TVAL Before = 10
> Length of TVAL After =  19
> TVAL = temp:26.62
> ```

You can use a dot to check it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    char tval[20] = "temp:26.62";

    size_t length = strlen(tval);

    printf("Length of TVAL Before = %zu\n\n", length);

    while(length < 19){

        tval[length] = ' ';
        length++;
    }

    tval[18] = '.';
    tval[19] = '\0';

    printf("TVAL = %s\n\n",tval);
    printf("Length of TVAL After =  %zu\n",length);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Length of TVAL Before = 10
> TVAL = temp:26.62        .
> Length of TVAL After =  19
> ```

Comment: The additional `tval[19] = '\0';` terminator is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```c
char tval[20];
sprintf(tval,"%-*s",19,"temp:26.62");
...
```

or

```c
char tval[20] = "temp:26.62";
sprintf(tval,"%-*s",19,tval);
```